# How do I get the program to print and then restart the code again

Tags: python, while-loop

I can not get the bit that is at the bottom to work (Does not print the bit inside the if statement just goes back to the top of the program).

This is code I have got so far.

I have tried moving around the break and adding some continues but I can't get anything to work.

```
while True:
    while True:
            numberOne = int(input("Enter a number between number 0 and 10"))
            numberTwo = int(input("Enter a seccond number between number 0 and 10"))

            if numberOne > 0 and numberTwo < 10 and numberTwo < 10 and  numberTwo > 0:

                print (numberOne + numberTwo)
                break
    break
    if numberOne < 0 or numberOne > 10 or numberTwo > 10 or numberTwo < 0:

        print("These numbers are not imbetween 0 and 10 ")
```

I expected the output to be "These numbers are not imbetween 0 and 10" and then do the script again.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    numberOne = int(input("Enter a number between number 0 and 10"))
    numberTwo = int(input("Enter a seccond number between number 0 and 10"))

    if 1 < numberOne < 10 and 1 < numberTwo < 10:

        print(numberOne + numberTwo)

    elif 0 > numberOne > 10 or 0 > numberTwo > 10:
        print("These numbers are not imbetween 0 and 10 ")
```

or:

```
i = True
while i:
    numberOne = int(input("Enter a number between number 0 and 10"))
    numberTwo = int(input("Enter a seccond number between number 0 and 10"))

    if 1 < numberOne < 10 and 1 < numberTwo < 10:
        print(numberOne + numberTwo)
        i = False

    elif 0 > numberOne > 10 or 0 > numberTwo > 10:
        print("These numbers are not imbetween 0 and 10 ")
```

I don't really undstand from the question the desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the code below will work, please confirm this is how you want it

```py
while True:
    numberOne = int(input("Enter a number between number 0 and 10: "))
    numberTwo = int(input("Enter a seccond number between number 0 and 10: "))
    if numberOne < 0 or numberOne > 10 or numberTwo > 10 or numberTwo < 0:
        print("Numbers not between 0 and 10! ")
    if numberOne > 0 and numberOne < 10 and numberTwo < 10 and  numberTwo > 0:
        print(numberOne + numberTwo)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without needing to use `break`. It is not very clear, what are you trying to do exactly, but this code will check the numbers and either sum and print or just print then it continues looping:

```
while True:
    numberOne = int(input("Enter a number between number 0 and 10: "))
    numberTwo = int(input("Enter a seccond number between number 0 and 10: "))

    if (numberOne in range(1,10)) and (numberTwo in range(1,10)):
        print (numberOne + numberTwo)
    else:
        print("These numbers are not between 0 and 10 ")
```

Comment: Upper limit is non-inclusive from range, no?

Comment: `[i for i in range(1,10)] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` so yes, upper limit is not-inclusive.

Comment: Oh, I thought the OP was asking for numbers 1 to 10, inclusive. But I apparently didn't read carefully enough.